# Dockerfile for Windows Container won't copy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm having trouble with simple `COPY` in to the container.

I've dumbed the replication of the issue down, and it can be replicated with the default of an ASP.NET MVC Web application project template. If you use the Visual Studio Enable Docker operation it will give you a simple Dockerfile in the same directory.

### This is my directory structure:

```
WebApplication1
├───Content
├───Controllers
├───Models
├───Properties
├───Scripts
└───Views
    ├───Home
    └───Shared
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
favicon.ico
Global.asax
Global.asax.cs
packages.config
Web.config
WebApplication1.csproj
```

### Default Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

The problem is that I have requirements in the broader project to use a private nuget repo, and so a **msbuild** within the container image build is required. (I'm omitting the private nuget add repo step here for brevity.)

### My Dockerfile

```
# Build stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
ARG source
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project file and restore dependencies
COPY WebApplication1.csproj .
RUN nuget restore WebApplication1.csproj

# Copy the source code and build the application
COPY . .
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release

# Publish the application
RUN msbuild /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=/app/PublishOutput

# Runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/PublishOutput .

# Expose the port on which your application will listen
EXPOSE 80

# Set the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["WebApplication1.dll"]
```

It won't find the csproj file to copy in. I've done `COPY . .`, but then it would find the project file that way either, as it doesn't get copied in. I've done multi-staged dotnet Core and have not seen this.

- Are there differences in Windows Containers in implmentations that I'm not seeing?
- Why does the vanilla .NET Windows Container dockerfile have `ARG source` as a passed in parameter?
- Visual Studio is doing the build and not a command-line `docker build`. Maybe the build context should be a different directory?

Any help is appreciated.